# Jquery, Keeping track of a variable number

Tags: jquery, loops

I'm currently making a site, where users can submit questionaries.

When making a questionary schema, users can add as many questions as they want. I use Jquery for

this functionality

```
   $('body').on('click', '.add_question', function() {

    var result = $(this).attr('data-result');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        url: (my_ajax_script.ajaxurl),
        data: ({action: 'add_question_1'}),
        success: function(msg) {

            $(result).append(msg);

        }
    });
});
```

Every question has an id, starting from 1, then  2, and so on. This html is

added to a table every time the user pushes the "add question" button.

```
function add_question_1() {
?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <textarea id="<?php echo $_SESSION['d'] ?>"></textarea> 
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
$_SESSION['d'] ++;
}
```

Now, when the user submit these questions to the database, i have no problem getting the value from

the id, like this:

```
var first_question = $("#1").val();
```

my problem is this:

the number of questions varies, there might be 1, or 100, and i cant figure out how to keep track of

how many questions to submit!

I will appreciate any answers, leading me in the right direction. I know this is not much information
, but i hope someone can understand this, and might have been in the same position.

THX!

FINAL SOLUTION:

```
   $('body').on('click', '.save_questionary', function() {


    var length = $('table textarea').length;
    var obj = $();
    var arr = $.makeArray(obj);
    for (i = 1; i <= length; i++) {

        arr.push($("#" + i).val());
    }
    var title = $("#title").val();
    var answer_required = $("#answer_required").val();
    var subject = $("#subject").val();
    var description = $("#description").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        url: (my_ajax_script.ajaxurl),
        data: ({action: 'add_question_2', arr: arr, title:title, subject:subject, answer_required:answer_required, description:description}),
        success: function(msg) {

            $(result).append(msg);

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You say you are using jQuery for this functionality (adding new questions), but it looks like you are using PHP.

Comment: Well, i didnt add the Jquery for that functionality. Because it doesnt really matter, not the source of my problem.

Comment: It's hard to tell what is going on with your code from what you've posted.

Comment: Just count the number table rows before you submit. `$('table tr').length`, that should give you total number of questions

Comment: #dcodesmith, im going to use this with a foor loop as #shidil dinesh suggested. Thx alot. God, i'm fairly new to this Jquery stuff, thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can add new questions you could count the number of textarea child elements in the form by

```
var count = $("#form textarea").length;
```

then put a for loop form 1 to count

```
var question = $("#"+i).val(); // where i is the loop counter
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert the Session variable like this in ASP.NET:
SESSION['d'] = Convert.ToInt32(SESSION['d']) + 1;